# Как правильно записать json файл?

Tags: python, парсер

Можете считать это продолжением предыдущих вопросов, но хочу этот парсер довести до конца.

Короче, как правильно записать json файл, что бы было 'имя фильма' - 'картинка фильма'

[image]

ну вот так, для каждого фильма отдельный словарь

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот что у меня сейчас

```
    def get_items(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    all_names= []
    headings = soup.find_all('h2')
    for i in headings:
        name = i.text
        all_names.append(name)
        # print(name)
    scripts = soup.find_all('script', type='application/ld+json')
    data = json.loads(scripts[1].text)

    all_items = []

    films = {}
    for idx in range(0, len(headings)):
        films[headings[idx].text.lstrip()] = data['image'][idx + 1]['url']

    for k, v in films.items():
        print('{}\r\n{}\r\n'.format(k, v))
    all_items.append({
        'name':all_names,
        'photos':films
    })



    with open('result_films.json','w') as file:
        json.dump(films, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
def main():
    get_items(url='https://www.thevoicemag.ru/lifestyle/films/luchshie-novogodnie-filmy/')
```

Comment: Ну я проверил, у вас всё правильно в `JSON`, там словарь формата "название фильма": "ссылка", что не так то, в чём ваш вопрос? Это один словарь. Нормальный `JSON`.

Comment: @CrazyElf, нужно что бы для каждого фильма был один словарь в json файле

Comment: Вы можете нормально задать вопрос?

Comment: Сергей Ш, я же говорил 'для каждого фильма, отдельный словарь'. Название + картинка

Answer (score 0):

> нужно что бы для каждого фильма был один словарь в json файле

Так до конца и не понятно что необходимо. Чтобы в json была куча словарей, по одному для каждого фильма?
Тогда поменяй вот эту часть:

```python
films = {'films': []}
for idx in range(0,len(headings)):
    films['films'].append({headings[idx].text.lstrip() : data['image'][idx+1]['url']})
```

Answer (score 0):

В вашем коде

`json.dump(films, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)`

заменить на

`json.dump(all_items, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)`

Альтернативный код:

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.thevoicemag.ru/lifestyle/films/luchshie-novogodnie-filmy/'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
names = [" ".join(x.text.split()) for x in soup.find_all('h2')]
photos = [x.meta['content'] for x in soup.find_all('div', class_='article-detail_tag_p')]
films = [{'name': name, 'photos': photo} for name, photo in zip(names, photos)]

with open('result_films.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    json.dump(films, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
```